# Why does the console output show two numbers rather than letters?

Tags: c#

My program is supposed to take the two middle values of a word, in this case "es". I used a second variable to get "s" as the program would already collect "e" however, when I run this program the values returned are integers instead of letters.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word = "Test";

        int wordLength = word.Count();

        if (wordLength % 2 == 0)
        {
            int middle = word[wordLength / 2];
            int nextAlong = middle + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Even number");
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", middle, nextAlong);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Odd number");
            Console.WriteLine(word[wordLength / 2]);    
        }
    }
}
```

The console output is

```
Even number
115,116
```

Comment: You need to treat middle variable as index (a number) `int middle = wordLength/2 ;` and then use the indexer to get the characters `Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", word[middle], word[nextAlong]);`

Comment: You need to extract with the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing into a `string` does return a `char` but because you’ve defined the `middle` and `nextAlong` variables as being of type `int`, they’re getting implicitly converted from `char` to `int`.

Try the following instead.

```
public static void Main( )
{
    string word = "Test";
    int wordLength = word.Length;

    if (wordLength % 2 == 0)
    {
        var middleIndex = wordLength / 2 - 1;
        char middle = word[middleIndex];
        char nextAlong = word[middleIndex + 1];
        Console.WriteLine("Even number");
        Console.WriteLine($"{middle},{nextAlong}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Odd number");
        Console.WriteLine(word[wordLength / 2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This post is good in that it also points out the logic flaw with the original code in how it calculates the "next" character. `middle + 1` is wrong in that it will make the next letter in the alphabet. Doing `+1` _on the index_ (`word[middleIndex + 1]`) is correct.

Comment: However, I think you need a `-1` when making `middleIndex`. `4/2=2`, and the middle indexes are 1 and 2, not 2 and 3.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah good point. I was mostly just trying to show where the OP went wrong with their variable declarations. I've updated.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help guys, However i noticed that,  var middleIndex = wordLength / 2 - 1;
        char middle = word[middleIndex]; char nextAlong = word[middleIndex + 1]; outputs "se" instead of "es", This error can be fixed by changing the code to var middleIndex = wordLength / 2;
        char middle = word[middleIndex]; char nextAlong = word[middleIndex - 1];. Hopefully this helps someone in the future

Comment: @Hobospider132 If this answer helped you, please make sure to accept the answer.